# javascript can't find blob

Tags: javascript, web, html5-video, blob, fetch-api

So I know that blobs are only available in the tab they were created in, but somehow I get an error message that the blob couldn't been found. It doesn't matter where I try it.

For example YouTube videos are blobs, I can get the object URL of it with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentSrc /// => 'blob:http://youtube.com/asddasd-asdasd-asdasd-asddsa'
```

now if I try to get the blob with

```
fetch(url)
```

I get an error that the blob couldn't been found.

Comment: Maybe the blob is no longer available, youtube downloads videos small chunks at a time, each chunk would be a different blob.

Answer (score 3):

Youtube videos blobURIs are not pointing to Blobs but to [MediaSources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/).

Blobs are not the only objects we can point to using the `URL.createObjectURL()` method, we used to be able to pass MediaStreams too, and more importantly to our case, we can still pass MediaSource objects.

```js
const source = new MediaSource();
const url = URL.createObjectURL( source ); // this doesn't throw
console.log( url ); // that's a valid blob URI

fetch( url ).catch( console.error ); // nothing to fetch there
```

YouTube does fetch the data as ArrayBuffers, and then populate a MediaSource with this data.

There is natively no way of retrieving the original MediaSource from the blobURI, and even though [we can override URL.createObjectURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572963/3702797) to get it back, we can't retrieve the actual data passed to the MediaSource anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fetch with a standard URL first, and then indicate that it should be interpreted as a blob.

```
const url = "http://youtube.com/asddasd-asdasd-asdasd-asddsa"
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(console.log)
```

But you might run into some [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues when fetching youtube!

Comment: If I do it with "blob:" then I get the "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error. If I do it without "blob:" I get a 404 error.

Comment: @Mointy can you check the Network tab of the DevTools to get more information on why the request fails?

Comment: Here is one image for a request with and without "blob":https://ibb.co/xHGYG6Y, 
https://ibb.co/ydWbK5V

Comment: the `blob:` protocol isn't [supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and seems to be forbidden (?) when requesting cross origin resources.

Comment: Since I use it in my content script in my browser extension, it should work. The content script is directly  injected into the site, so there is no cross origin problem. I will try it in google chrome, I was using edge with chromium engine(which means, it should still work)...

Comment: nope, it doesnt even work in chrome. Same errors. 404 or file not found.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm tapped out of top-of-my-head ideas